# Is there a REST API for Google Play where I can look up the list of apps like the iTunes lookup/search service?

Tags: search, app-store-connect, lookup, google-play

E.g. http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=angry&entity=software

I'm trying to make an autocomplete field where the user type in the search term like "angry" and I'll get results from Google Play on the list of related apps like "Angry Birds".